# Getting number of shares and likes for a facebook video

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

How to get overall number of shares and likes for a Facebook video?
If you want to get number of shares/likes for any link you can use
http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls={URL}

But this is not working for a video hosted on Facebook. Is there any way to get total number of shares and likes for a Facebook Video?

Comment: You should stop using that old REST stuff, it has been deprecated for quite a while now; use Graph API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/video#edges

Comment: @CBroe Yeap, but still it does not solves the problem, it will show number likes on the original post, but if you some user will "share" it and his posts will get likes, this will not add them to original post likes. While I want to get overall stats

Comment: Use `{video_id}?fields=likes.summary(true),shares` you will get what you want

Comment: @AdamAzad agian, this will show likes from original post, I want to get likes from original post and all shares/reshares likes. Not number of shares,but sum of likes each shared post got with original post likes